# deleting git repository completely

Tags: git

I want to remove git completely from my project folder. I tried the command

```
rm -r .git
```

on the directory of my project folder but it doesn't work. The terminal screen just filled up with red texts and scrolls down and never stops.

[image: here are the errors on the terminal]

Comment: "*You do not have sufficient access rights to perform this operation*".

Comment: @GinoMempin , yes with PowerShell and adding -force, but on my vscode the source control icon telling that it has +1k of pending changes, this means the repository hasn't been deleted yet?

Comment: Assuming you did successfully delete the .git folder, sometimes with many/big changes, there's a delay to VS Code's Source Control panel. Try reloading the VS Code window.

Comment: Please don't post screen shots of error messages, and in particular not low-contrast screen shots which are hard to read for some visitors. See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Comment: @GinoMempin it has changed to a clock symbol, but I'm getting this message on vscode :The git repository at 'c:\' has too many active changes, only a subset of Git features will be enabled.

Comment: Voting is personal, secret, and discretionary; advising us on how to vote, especially based on speculation about who voted how, is only likely to get you more downvotes.

Comment: @tripleee  i apologize, 
I just commented on the votes because I tried to copy the error but I explained that I couldn't  because the screen was scrolling so fast. sorry again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Linux or git-bash then you can try any one of these commands->

```
rm -r -f Folder_Name

rm -rf Folder_Name
```

This will resolve your problem.

You aren't able to delete using just `rm -r Folder_Name` because the contents inside the 3 git files named .  ,  ..  ,  and .git  are write-protected. Therefore just recursion won't help. You need to use -f keyword to forcefully delete the write-protected files.

Comment: i'm on windows, if I want to try Linux commands is there any consoles for windows that accepts  Linux command?

Comment: @msunknown Yes, you can try installing git bash